# How to cast namedtuple into tuple

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

How to do the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000159/how-to-cast-tuple-into-namedtuple)?

I have a list of namedtuples that I built by iterating a pandas dataframe:

```
list = []
for currRow in dataframe.itertuples():
    list.append(currRow)
```

How to convert this list of namedtuples into a list of tuples? Note that itertuples() returns namedtuples.

Comment: A named tuple *is* a tuple; the type returned by `namedtuple` is a subclass of `tuple`, and a named-tuple value should be usable anywhere a `tuple` value is expected.

Comment: @chepner Pickling a list of namedtuples fails, but pickling a list of tuples works: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1382. "namedtuples aren't serializable under cloudpickle"

Comment: That's unfortunate; sounds like a bug. `T = namedtuple("T", "foo bar"); t = T(1,2); pickle.dumps(t)` produces `b'\x80\x03c__main__\nT\nq\x00K\x01K\x02\x86q\x01\x81q\x02.'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just put it through the `tuple()` constructor:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple

>>> foo = namedtuple('foo', ('bar', 'baz'))
>>> nt = foo(1,2)
>>> nt
foo(bar=1, baz=2)
>>> tuple(nt)
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't name your variables after builtins.

To answer your question, you can just use the `tuple` constructor; assuming your source `list` is named `l`:

```
l_tuples = [tuple(t) for t in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Just construct the tuple from the namedtuple as param.

```
>>> X = namedtuple('X', 'y')
>>> x1 = X(1)
>>> x2 = X(2)
>>> x3 = X(3)
>>> x_list = [x1, x2, x3]
>>> x_tuples = [tuple(i) for i in x_list]
>>> x_tuples
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
>>>
```