# Type Error: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I am trying to implement a robot environment which is a part of a free course provided by Intel. There are multiple files in the course assignment, `MakeItLearn.py` is the one we were supposed to edit and add a network of our own there for the training of the bot.

But when I try to collect data using the `ExploreAndCollect.py` file, which Intel also provides and we're not told to change anything in that file, it throws the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ExploreAndCollect.py", line 268, in <module>     env = BotEnv()   File "ExploreAndCollect.py", line 35, in __init__     self.BuildBot(50.01, 450.01, 20)   File "ExploreAndCollect.py", line 69, in BuildBot     BoxPoints = list(map(Vec2d, [(-size, -size), (-size, size), (size,size), (size, -size)])) TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Here's the code where the class and the function is defined:

```
class BotEnv:
    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize Required Variables
        self.crashed = False
        self.DetectCrash = 0
        self.space = pymunk.Space()
        self.BuildBot(50.01, 450.01, 20)  <---------------------------------------------
        self.walls = []
        self.WallShapes = []
        self.WallRects = []
        ## Add Walls To The Map ###
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(200, 50, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(200, 125, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(200, 550, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(200, 450, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(400, 350, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(400, 250, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(500, 250, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(600, 250, 50)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        WallBody, WallShape, WallRect = self.BuildWall(115, 1050, 500)
        self.WallRects.append(WallRect)
        self.PreviousAction = 0

    def BuildBot(self, x, y, r):
        ### Build The Bot Object ###
        size = r
        BoxPoints = list(map(Vec2d, [(-size, -size), (-size, size), (size,size), (size, -size)])) <----------------
        mass  = 0.5
        moment = pymunk.moment_for_poly(mass,BoxPoints, Vec2d(0,0))
        self.Bot = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
        self.Bot.position = (x,y) # Declare Bot Position
        self.Bot.angle = 1.54     # Set the Bot Angle
        BotDirection = Vec2d(PointsFromAngle(self.Bot.angle)) # Get The Direction Vector From Angle
        self.space.add(self.Bot)
        self.BotRect = pygame.Rect(x-r,600-y-r, 2*r, 2*r)
        return self.Bot
```

I looked at the function call, which is also mentioned above, and it has the `y` component in it so I can't seem to find what seems to be causing the error. The python environment requirements were Python 2.7 and all versions of Python 3

Comment: It seems `Vec2d` takes 2 arguments, `x` and `y`. It is getting only one, a tuple with the `x` and `y` coordinates (e.g. `(size, size)`). So `x` has a wrong value and `y` is not set.

Comment: You can try to replace `map` with [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

Comment: If I use `starmap` then I get an error - `File "ExploreAndCollect.py", line 76, in BuildBot
    BotDirection = Vec2d(PointsFromAngle(self.Bot.angle)) # Get The Direction Vector From Angle
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Comment: That means using `starmap` fixed the bug on line 69 and now you have the same bug on line 76. You could fix that using `Vec2d(*PointsFromAngle(self.Bot.angle))` (note the *). But the question is why does this error keep popping up? Are you using the correct `Vec2d`?

Comment: As I wrote in the description above, This file wasn't created by me, it was created by Intel as a free course, but when I try to run the simulation using the file above it throws an error. Here's the link for the course where you can download the code files : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/training/course-deep-learning-robotics.html

Comment: This question seems related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000159/how-to-cast-tuple-into-namedtuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is going wrong?

The code that comes with the course you are doing uses [pymunk.vec2d.Vec2d](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.vec2d.html). There recently has been an update to `Vec2d` making it a [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple). Before that change, `Vec2d` could be created using a tuple:

```
vec2d = Vec2d((x, y))
```

That is no longer possible. `Vec2d` being a named tuple with fields `x` and `y` can be created using: separate arguments, `*` syntax for tuple unpacking or [Vec2d._make](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make):

```
v1 = Vec2d(3, 4)
v2 = Vec2d(*(3, 4))
v3 = Vec2d._make((3, 4))
```

This is all described in [the Changelog for Pymunk](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/changelog.html) (version 6.0.0):

> - Made Vec2d a subclass of NamedTuple.
>
>   - Vec2ds has to be constructed with separate x and a y values.
>   - Vec2d((1,2)) can be changed to Vec2d(*(1,2)).
>   - Vec2d(Vec2d(1,2)) can be changed to Vec2d(*Vec2d(1,2)).
>   - Vec2d() can be changed to Vec2d(0,0) or Vec2d.zero().
>   - Vec2d(1,2) is no longer equal to [1,2] since they are of different types. (but Vec2d(1,2) == (1,2) is still true)

#### So what can you do?

You probably should let the people at Intel know that their code is broken with Pymunk 6.0.0 and higher. For the time being you could try to use a version of Pymunk prior to 6.0.0 (that is probably the best solution) or you could change the code that comes with the course and use one of the options above.